# removing some rows from a text file in pandas and make a new file

Tags: pandas, text-files, skip

I have a text file which has a complicated structure and I would like to make a tab separated file with 10 columns. the problem is at the beginning of this file there are some useless lines which must be removed. 
in this file there is a line which starts with `#CHROM` which will be the first line of result text file.

here is a n example of my input file:

```
##bcftools_filterCommand=filter -e 'SOMATIC_PON_COUNT!="." && MIN(SOMATIC_PON_COUNT) > 3' -s SOMATIC_PON -m+ -O z -o /sample/output/180614_HMFregCPCT_FR16985640_FR16985806_CPCT02170033/somaticVariants/CPC
T02170033R_CPCT02170033T/CPCT0217003ted.pon
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  CPCT02170033T
1   819393  .   T   C   .   PASS    AC=0;AF=0;AN=0;MAPPABILITY  GT:AD:DP    0/1:75,15:91
```

expected output (with 2 lines):

```
CHROM   POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  CPCT02170033T
1   819393  .   T   C   .   PASS    AC=0;AF=0;AN=0;MAPPABILITY  GT:AD:DP    0/1:75,15:91
```

to do so I wrote the following code in python3:

```
with open("myfile.txt") as f:
    total = f.readlines()
    skip_value = total.index("#CHROM\n")
    df = pd.read_csv("myfile.txt", skiprows=skip_value, sep="\t")
```

but it gives this error:

```
ValueError: '#CHROM\n' is not in list
```

do you know how to fix the code?

Comment: if the row is always in the first row why not try `skiprows=1` in your `pd.read_csv`

Comment: @Datanovice: as mentioned in the question, that is not the first line. there is always going to be few lines before that which must be removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Import libries
import pandas as pd 

# open the file 
with open("myfile.txt") as f:
    skip_value = 1
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line.split()[0] == "#CHROM":
            skip_value += 1

# Load data from txt with pandas
df = pd.read_csv("myfile.txt", skiprows=skip_value, sep="\t")

# Print the final df
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
    #CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  CPCT02170033T
0   1   819393  .   T   C   .   PASS    AC=0;AF=0;AN=0;MAPPABILITY  GT:AD:DP    0/1:75,15:91
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there, since `total` is a list, you have to iterate through all the elements to find the index of the element that matches your substring.

`with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    total = f.readlines()
    for elem in total:
        if elem.find('#CHROM') > -1:
            skip_value = total.index(elem)
    df = pd.read_csv('myfile.txt, skiprows=skip_value, sep = '\t')`

Comment: Apologies for the indentation.